# How do you get into the Jungle Temple?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I cant mine the blocks around it and the door is locked.

How do I get in?

Answer (score 3):

If you search all around the outside of the Jungle Temple you will eventually find an entrance (it is generally top left or top right). However it is blocked by a locked door.

In order to unlock the door you will need to get the Temple Key. To get the Temple Key, defeat Plantera, it has a 100% chance to drop the Temple Key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fight Plantera, by breaking the pulsing bulbs in the jungle, (You need to beat 1 mech boss to get them to spawn) and it will always drop a Jungle Temple Key, so then you use that key to get in the temple.